# Redirecting my echo output to a file

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am implementing a logic in shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=">> /tmp/testlog.txt"

echo "My log output" $LOGOUTPUT
```

Output:
My log output >> /tmp/testlog.txt

Is there any way to redirect  my echo output to /tmp/testlog.txt instead of above line getting displayed on console.

Note: Please dont suggest below solution

```
echo "My log ouptut" >> /tmp/testlog.txt
```

Any other solution apart from this ?

Comment: whats wrong this suggestion? echo "My log ouptut" >> /tmp/testlog.txt

Comment: `LOGFILE=">> /tmp/testlog.txt"` creates a string. That is a single entity. You cannot use that in the way you try to. Your `echo` statement receives two arguments with your attempt. That is not what you want.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the suggestion. I have a special requirement where I need to toggle my echo command output to serial or to a file. I should be able to do that by changing the value of LOGFILE variable. So finding an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the redirection characters outside of your `LOGFILE` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=/tmp/testlog.txt

echo "My log output" >> $LOGFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exec > >(tee -i $logfile)`

I use it this way usually :

```
function start_logging() {
    logfile="$1"
    touch $logfile
    exec > >(tee -i $logfile)
    exec 2>&1 #also redirect stderr
    return 0
}
```

Call this function giving it /tmp/test.log for example, it will log all your program output in the file and prevent it from being displayed on std and err outputs.

EDIT:
Redirect ONLY to file   : `>> "filename.t 2>&1`

Comment: This doesnt solve my requirement. I need all echo output to be redirected to stdout or to a log file based on value assigned to  LOGOUTPUT varaiable

Answer (score 0):

```
function logme()
{
    #Send logs to logfile
    logfile="/tmp/logfile.txt"

    #Send logs to stdout
    #logfile="/dev/stdout"

    cat >> $logfile
}

echo "Hello" | logme
echo "Friend" | logme
```